# 'Object' named class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

Does it have any drawbacks if I use Object as a name for my class inside module?

```
module Some
  class Object; end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually, this code ought to work with no problems, since it's in a module and thus namespaced.  For a simple test:

```
module Some
  class Object
    def foo
      "bar"
    end
  end
end

Some::Object.new.foo # "bar"
Some::Object.new.class # "Some::Object"

# And it doesn't pollute the global namespaced Object class:
Object.new.respond_to?(:foo) # false
```

It could potentially be confusing or ambiguous, however, if you include Some in another class or module, inside which Object will refer to Some::Object.  It still won't affect anything outside that class or module, though.

Comment: This is the correct answer: The only real drawback is that it's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

There are some pitfalls, but it works. If you do this, you'll expand the Object class that is already in Ruby.

```
class Object
  def hello
  end
end
```

When you namespace it you'll create a new class, though, in that namespace.

```
module Foo
  class Object
    # ...
  end
end
```

Technically speaking, this is not a problem.

One downside is that you have to use `::Object` when you want to refer to the built-in `Object` class. You don't doo that very often, though, so it's not a big problem.

The other problem is that can be very confusing for other developers, which you should take into consideration. It's hard to tell from your snippet what this `Some::Object` class of yours does, but perhaps `Some::Record`, `Some::Entity` makes more sense.

Answer (score -2):

`Object` is a reserved word in Ruby, so you should not use it as a name for your class.

Comment: Object is not a reserved word in Ruby - it's a globally defined constant that refers to a particular class, much like String, Hash, etc.  Reserved words in Ruby are things like `if`, `return`, etc.